# My asp web application master page is rendering even when wrong page url is entered

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404, master-pages

My asp web application has several master pages. Even when I enter wrong url (www.domain.com/lwkenfldskfnslkfnsldkfnsdlkfnsdlkfn), the master page is rendering the header and footer of the website and also some other content instead of showing the iis default 404 page error. Please help

My error page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/error.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="404.aspx.cs" Inherits="DiwanAlwan.error404" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


<div class="error-404 background background-color-dark background-image-main-404">
<div class="fp-table">
<div class="fp-table-cell center"
<div class="container">
<div class="margin-bottom-40">
<h1><span class="page">page</span><span>404</span></h1>
<h2>The product not found</h2>
</div>
<p>
<span>Please try one of the following pages</span>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary margin-left-10">Home Page</a>
</p>
</div><!-- /.container -->
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- /.error-404 -->


</asp:Content
```

My web config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/404.aspx">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

MY Master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="error.master.cs" Inherits="DiwanAlwan.error" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to post your `web.config` and your custom error page

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="404.aspx" responseMode="File" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="500.aspx" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Post your `404.aspx` page as well

Comment: i have edited my question with web config and error page

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new blank Masterpage and use it in your `404.aspx` page

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I tried your solution but it didnt seem to work. is there any other way ?

Comment: @HusainTatiwala have you tried adding the 404 page again with that new blank master ?

Comment: Yes i created a master page as Error.Master. Then I added 404.aspx to that master page. Below is the web config:          <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.Master">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>

Comment: Please ensure to add `MasterPageFile="~/error.Master" ` in page tag of your `404.aspx` as well

Comment: yes i have added the line. I have attached that code below:     <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/error.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="404.aspx.cs" Inherits="DiwanAlwan.error404" %>

Comment: This is weird,  clean your solution try rebuilding

Comment: I did that several times. I am updating my question with the master page and the error page. please check the updates im making. Im sure im making some silly mistake.